# What will happen to the bulb of the circuit after closing the switch?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Say it connects a bulb with the circuit below, with the switch $S$ open. Every cable has negligible resistance and the battery has no internal resistance.

*What happens to the brightness of the bulb after closing down the circuit?*

[image: Photo of the circuit]

My thought is that after activating that third resistance, it will form a parallel pair of resistance with the second resistance $$\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}$$ means the resistance will decrease and the intensity will increase since $$I=I_1+I_2+\dots$$ causing the difference of potential in $R_2$ to be the same (since parallel resistors) and an increase in intensity, which means more brightness to the bulb? Not sure at all so I was wondering if anyone could shine a light on this.

Comment: Build it and see! More fun than theory...

Comment: @JohnDoty I appreciate that but I’m not in conditions to build one. Instead it would help me understand the theory better if you answered me.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The current will increase, the bulb will get a little brighter.

Comment: @Dale great. And does the difference of potential in the second resistor stay the same as well? Since they are in parallel.

Comment: @YupA the potential across the parallel resistors (switch closed) will be less than the potential across the single resistor (switch opened). You should be able to calculate that

Comment: @Dale wait how? I thought $V_1=V_2=\dots$ for parallel resistors? And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are about right. According to [resistors in parallel & series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits)

##### Before closing switch

$R_1$ and $R_2$ are in series, current can't divide between them, so total current will be :
$$ I = \frac {V}{R_1 + R_2} \tag 1$$

##### After closing switch

Current will go though $R_1$, but then it will split between $R_2$ and $R_3$, meaning that your $R_1$ is in sequential connection of circuit, but $R_2$ and $R_3$ - in parallel circuit part, so total current will be :

$$ I = \frac {V}{R_1 + \frac {R_2 R_3}{R_2+R_3}} \tag 2,$$

Let's assume that $R_3=R_2$, so (2) will become as :
$$ I = \frac {V}{R_1 + \frac 12 R_2}  \tag 3,$$

And
$$ R_1 + \frac 12 R_2 < R_1 + R_2 \tag 4,$$

So in effect after closing the switch you will increase current, due to reducing total resistivity and hence bulb will go brighter. The overall result is when you add parallel circuit part,- it acts as if you would be reducing second resistivity $R_2$ in the previous circuit instead.

Of course, if your $R_3$ is very high, say $100R_2$, then reduction of total resistance will be very small, like $R_1 + 0.99R_2$, but principle idea holds.

Comment: very appreciated, crystal clear. I have a very similar question but with capacitors in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751061/358836 which I would love to be answered.